# Add Contact to a ContactGroup

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to add contacts that are in MyContacts into other contact groups. I feel like i've written it correctly but it is not working:-

```
function myFunction() {
    var MyContact = ContactsApp.getContactsByEmailAddress('XXXX.XXXX@Pearson.com'); 
    var MyGroup = ContactsApp.getContactGroup('Sample');
        MyGroup.addContact(MyContact); 
}
```

XXXX.XXXX@Pearson.com is in my contacts list and I have already created the group *Sample* but I get the message of 'Cannot convert to . (line 4) Dismiss'. Line for being:-

```
MyGroup.addContact(MyContact);
```

Any ideas? I looked around and could not find an answer.

Regards
Gary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sample code works if the group exists :

```
function addtContactTogroup() {
  var contact = ContactsApp.getContact('emailAdress')  
  var group = ContactsApp.getContactGroup('groupName')
          group.addContact(contact)
      }
```

It's almost the same as yours, I know ! , but it doesn't throw any error ... please keep us informed it it fails for you.

Comment: How strange, so 'getContactsByEmailAddress' doesn't work? Well your suggestion has worked for me. Thank you!

Comment: If I run the code, it doesn't seem to work, if I then try with someone elses email address, the previous email address get inserted, but not the one i've just run. **Hold off - I think this is an account refresh problem, let me test and get back to you. I logged out and back in and this time they were both there**

Comment: Hi Serge, there appears to be an issue with reloading the contact information, if I log out and back in then the contacts look at need. thank you for your support here!

Answer (score -1):

Zoe je zoiets als dit:

```
function myFunction() {
  var Mycontacts = ContactsApp.getContactsByGroup("AnyGroupName");
   for (var i=0; i<Mycontacts.length; i++) {
          if (Mycontacts[i]) {
            Mycontacts[i].addToGroup("AnyGroupNameWereYouLikeToPutIt");
          }
   }
}
```